# Привязка содержимого класса к TreeView

Tags: java, javafx

Допустим у меня есть некие классы:

```
public class Person{
    String name;
    int age;
    List<Work> works;
    List<Certificate> certificates;
}

public class Work{
    String companyName;
    String positionName;
    int experienceAtMonth;
}

public class Certificate{
    String organization;
    String position;
    Date date;
}
```

Суть в том, что мне необходимо отобразить в `TreeView`:

- экземпляры `Person`, внутри которых отображается список работ и сертификатов.

Остальные поля должны отображаться в отдельном контейнере (типа `TextField`) при нажатии на соотв. ноду.

Можно конечно формировать строки, а при работе с данными искать по названию. Однако мне это кажется костылем и я бы хотел его избежать и использовать какой-то binding, однако не могу понять, каким образом описать данное поведение.

По сему, подскажите, пожалуйста возможные реализации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: + крайне примитивный биндинг

Добавляем интерфейс:

```
public interface Titlable {
    String getTitle();
    StringProperty getProperty();
}
```

Дописываем ваши классы:

```
public class Person implements Titlable {
    String name;
    int age;
    List<Work> works;
    List<Certificate> certificates;
    public String getTitle() {
        return name;
    }

    private StringProperty property;

    public StringProperty getProperty() {
        if (null == property)
            return property = new SimpleStringProperty( name + " " + age );
        return property;
    }
}

public class Work implements Titlable{
    String companyName;
    String positionName;
    int experienceAtMonth;
    public String getTitle() {
        return companyName;
    }
    private StringProperty property;

    public StringProperty getProperty() {
        if (null == property)
           return property = new SimpleStringProperty( companyName + " " + positionName );
        return property;
    }
}

public class Certificate implements Titlable{
    String organization;
    String position;
    Date date;
    public String getTitle() {
        return organization;
    }

    private StringProperty property;

    public StringProperty getProperty() {
        if (null == property)
            return property = new SimpleStringProperty( organization + " " + position + " " + date );
        return property;
    }

}
```

Собственно само дерево:

```
public class CustomTree extends TreeView<Titlable> {

    private final ObservableList<Person> persons;
    private final Main main;    

    public CustomTree( ObservableList<Person> persons, Main main ) {
        this.persons = persons;
        this.main = main;

        TreeItem<Titlable> rootItem = new TreeItem<Titlable>();
        rootItem.setExpanded( true );
        this.setShowRoot( false );
        this.setCellFactory( p -> new TreeCell<Titlable>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem( Titlable t, boolean empty ) {
                super.updateItem( t, empty );
                setText( t == null ? null : t.getTitle() );
            }
        });

        for ( Person p : persons ) {
            TreeItem<Titlable> pItem = new TreeItem<Titlable>( p );
            rootItem.getChildren().add( pItem );
            Titlable fake1 = new Titlable() {
                public String getTitle() { return "Works"; }
                private StringProperty property = new SimpleStringProperty( "-" );
            };
            Titlable fake2 = new Titlable() {
                public String getTitle() { return "Certificates"; }
                private StringProperty property = new SimpleStringProperty( "-" );
            };
            TreeItem<Titlable> f1Item = new TreeItem<Titlable>( fake1 );
            TreeItem<Titlable> f2Item = new TreeItem<Titlable>( fake2 );
            pItem.getChildren().addAll( f1Item, f2Item );
            for ( Work w : p.works ) {
                f1Item.getChildren().add( new TreeItem<Titlable>( w ) );
            }
            for ( Certificate c : p.certificates ) {
                f2Item.getChildren().add( new TreeItem<Titlable>( c ) );
            }
        }
        setRoot( rootItem );

        EventDispatcher originalDispatcher = this.getEventDispatcher();
        this.setEventDispatcher( new NotExpandedEventDispatcher( originalDispatcher ) );
    }

    private class NotExpandedEventDispatcher implements EventDispatcher{

        private final EventDispatcher originDispatcher;

        public NotExpandedEventDispatcher( EventDispatcher originDispatcher ){
            this.originDispatcher = originDispatcher;
        }

        @Override
        public Event dispatchEvent( Event event, EventDispatchChain tail ) {
            if ( event instanceof MouseEvent ) {
                if ( ((MouseEvent)event).getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY &&
                        ((MouseEvent)event).getClickCount() >= 2 ) {
                    if ( !event.isConsumed() ) {
                        TreeItem<Titlable> selectedItem = getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                        main.doSomething( selectedItem .getValue() );
                    }
                    event.consume();
                }
            }else if ( event instanceof KeyEvent ){
                if ( ((KeyEvent)event).getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER ){
                    if ( !event.isConsumed() ) {
                        TreeItem<Titlable> selectedItem = getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                        main.doSomething( selectedItem .getValue() );
                    }
                    event.consume();
                }
            }
            return originDispatcher.dispatchEvent( event, tail );
        }
    }
}
```

Проверяем:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private TextArea ta;

    @Override
    public void start( Stage stage ) {

        ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.<Person>observableArrayList();

        Work work1 = new Work();
        Work work2 = new Work();
        Work work3 = new Work();
        Work work4 = new Work();
        Work work5 = new Work();
        Work work6 = new Work();
        Work work7 = new Work();
        Work work8 = new Work();
        work1.companyName = "roga i kapbIta 1";
        work2.companyName = "roga i kapbIta 2";
        work3.companyName = "roga i kapbIta 3";
        work4.companyName = "roga i kapbIta 4";
        work5.companyName = "roga i kapbIta 5";
        work6.companyName = "roga i kapbIta 6";
        work7.companyName = "roga i kapbIta 7";
        work8.companyName = "roga i kapbIta 8";

        Certificate certificate1 = new Certificate();
        Certificate certificate2 = new Certificate();
        Certificate certificate3 = new Certificate();
        Certificate certificate4 = new Certificate();
        certificate1.organization = "kapbIta i roga 1";
        certificate2.organization = "kapbIta i roga 2";
        certificate3.organization = "kapbIta i roga 3";
        certificate4.organization = "kapbIta i roga 4";

        Person a = new Person();
        Person b = new Person();
        Person c = new Person();
        a.name = "ivan";
        b.name = "da";
        c.name = "mar'ya";
        a.works = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( work1, work2, work3 ) );
        b.works = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( work4, work5, work6 ) );
        c.works = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( work7, work8 ) );
        a.certificates = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( certificate1 ) );
        b.certificates = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( certificate2 ) );
        c.certificates = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( certificate3, certificate4 ) );

        persons.addAll( a, b, c );

        Parent container = new CustomTree( persons, this );
        ta = new TextArea();

        Scene scene = new Scene( new HBox( container, ta ) );
        stage.setWidth( 650 );
        stage.setHeight( 600 );
        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void doSomething( Titlable t ) {
        ta.textProperty().unbind();
        ta.textProperty().bind( t.getProperty() );
    }

}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Осталось добавить динамический (по событию смены выбранного элемента) биндинг между каким-нибудь TextArea.textProperty и активным (выделенным) элементом дерева. Ну и unbind'ить не забываем.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Насчет биндинга хотелось бы уточнить. Судя по Вашему коду, выбирается объект типа TreeItem<Titlable>, тогда каким образом описать, что объект определенного класса показывает свои поля в той же TextArea? И второй момент: я так понимаю, нет альтернативного способа, чтобы как, например, в xStream можно было аннотировать необходимые поля и на их основе построить дерево?

Comment: Про биндинг я ничего не писал, но самый простой вариант наверное будет по событию ( `MouseEvent`, `KeyEvent` или ещё что ) проверять `Titlable instanceof Person` и далее явно приводить и биндить. Можно расширить интерфейс. Про альтернативные способы ничего сказать не могу.

Comment: @AndreyM так вроде instanceof очень долгий и медленный. Сейчас это не так актуально, но когда записей будет на пару порядков больше - это может аукнуться. Я изначально похожим образом думал делать, но меня как раз остановили перспективы расширения и поддержки кода.

Comment: Вот подробно про TreeView: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/javafx-treeview-example/

Comment: @AndreyM огромное спасибо! Если не затруднит, объясните на пальцах суть cellFactory и eventDispatcher'а.

Comment: @I.Perevoz На пальцах не получится, но краткая суть: что один, что другой - это переопределение стандартного поведения. В случае `cellFactory` - переопределение отрисовки( содержимое, цвет и т.п. ) в зависимости от элемента ячейка. Его поведение по умолчанию `setGraphic( (Node)cell.item )` если элемент `instanceof Node`, иначе `setText( cell.item.toString() )`. `eventDispetcher` отвечает за передачу события в цепочке доставки с возможностью обработать `event`, изменить, подменить, отклонить и т.п.